# Counting values of each classification code using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, summarizing, unique-value

I feel like this is an easy fix, but I'm struggling to just get a count of how many attributes I have for each value in a certain column for an Attribute table.

I have a column of landfire classification code is associated with my GPS points, and I want to know how many points I have that are classified as 7610, how many points are classified as 7611, and so on for each unique code.

Anyone know or have ideas?

I'm using QGIS 3.16.

Answer (score 9):

If you symbolise a layer by your chosen attribute, and then right click the layer in the list of layers, you can select "Show Feature Count". This will then calculate and display a number next to each category, which indicates how many features are in that category.[image]

Answer (score 9):

Use built-in Processing algorithm "Statistics by Categories" available in the Processing Toolbox like below. It will return in a new layer the categories and count for selected field.

[image: Statistics by Categories Window]

It can also be called through PyQGIS

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
result = processing.run("qgis:statisticsbycategories", {
    'INPUT':layer, # Can be a path instead '/vsicurl/https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.geojson'
    'VALUES_FIELD_NAME':'',
    'CATEGORIES_FIELD_NAME':['type'],
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'
})
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['OUTPUT'])
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the ["Group Stats"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) Plugin. Install it and then choose `Vector -> Group Stats`.

Choose your input file, drag `"Count"` into the Columns box, drag your categorical field into the Rows box and another field like `"id"` into the `"Value"` box. Then Press <kbd>Calculate</kbd>. You will get a table showing each unique value in the categorical field and the count of each, in a format that can be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use PyQGIS:

```py
from collections import Counter

layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('ok_bs_riks')[0] #Change to match your layername
fieldname = 'kkod' #Change

c = Counter((val[fieldname] for val in layer.getFeatures()))
for key, val in c.items():
    print(key, val)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A short and easy way is to use QGIS expressions:

**Simple expression with repeated calculation**

```
count( landfire classification, group_by:=landfire classification)
```

Replace `landfire classification` with the name of the attribute you use for classification. For the simple version, you're done. See in what follows for some more options.

---

**Where to use the expression**

This expression can e.g. been used with field calculator to create a new attribute. See screenshot: every entry blue has a `count` value of 24, so there are 24 points categorizes as `blue`. So the output is repeated for every feature. If you want to just calculate it once, see below the screenshot.

[image]

**More complex expression without repeated calculation**

To calculate the number of features for each category just once, you can use the following expression. To avoid repeating calculation, just select one feature an make sure the box next to `Only update 1 selected features` is checked. Or simply copy the result from the preview (see next screenshot), without applying the field calculator. To do this, you could also use any other place in QGIS where you can use QGIS expressions - like `select by expression`, data driven override for styling etc.

```
aggregate( 
    @layer,
    'concatenate_unique',
    attribute (
        get_feature_by_id(
            @layer, 
            $id
        ), 
        'colors'
    ) ||': '    || 
    ( array_length (
        array_agg( 
            colors, 
            group_by:=colors
        )
    ) ),
    concatenator:=', '
)
```

This expression returns a string, in my case: `'blue: 24, green: 15, red: 27, white: 17, yellow: 17'` as can be seen in the preview at the bottom of the expression editor in the next screenshot:

[image]

**Explanation**

With `aggregate( )` and the argument `'concatenate_unique'`  you get a string containing all unique entries (categories) like `bluegreenredwhiteyellow`. To each of these values, the number of occurences is added with `||` (thus again concatenating). This number is retrieved with the `array_length()` part that contains the same princicple as above, but this time using `array_agg` instead of `count`.

**Using `maps` to get key:value pairs**

You can convert the output to a `map` (list of `key:value` pairs, comparable to Python dictionaries, see [Wikipedia: Associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)) to be able to query single values from it. Use `hstore_to_map( )`:

```
hstore_to_map( 
    aggregate( 
        @layer,
        'concatenate_unique',
        attribute (
            get_feature_by_id(
                @layer, 
                $id
            ), 
            'colors'
        ) ||'=>'    || 
        ( array_length (
            array_agg( 
                colors, 
                group_by:=colors
            )
        ) ),
        concatenator:=', '
    )
)
```

From this, you can now simply get the number of features with a certain value, say how often the value `red` appears:

`map_get ( [map], 'red')` - replace `[map]` with the `hstore_to_map( )` expression from above. Output is: `27`.

[image]

Comment: Where would I type in this expression?  The *Field Calculator*, or???  Then, where would the results appear?  A screenshot of how the expression should be used would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, field calculator: see updated answer

Comment: Ahah!  Thanks for the quick response.  Calculating just once would be preferable, please show that if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your time!